# How do I make Angular this.clipboard.copy work inside a subscribe?

Tags: angular, clipboard

A simple clipboard copy works until I move it inside a subscription

**Works**

```
copyStuff() {
  this.clipboard.copy('xxxxxxxx');
}
```

**Doesn't work**

```
copyStuff() {
  this.service.getText()
    .subscribe({
      next: () => {
        this.clipboard.copy('xxxxxxxx');
        console.log('here')
      }
    })
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix? I already tried setTimeout and var that = this.

Unfortunately outside my project, everything works as expected.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hs66nf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-clipboard-overview-example.ts

But inside my project, I have to click the button 3 times(so 3 requests) for the text to be copied. Clicking one or two times doesn't work.

Comment: What is the clipboard? Do you use Angular CDK or what? A simple reproduction would be great.

Comment: Yes angular cdk, import { Clipboard } from '@angular/cdk/clipboard';

Answer (score 0):

Well, somehow the page was losing focus and I think cdk clipboard was not erroring out. I switched to navigator.clipboard.writeText and that errored out.

Before the text was ready to be copied I now refocus the button that was clicked.

```
copySomething(ref: MatButton) {
     this.service.get(user._id).subscribe(
        {
          next: resp => {
            ref.focus();
            navigator.clipboard.writeText(resp.text)
              .then().catch(e => console.error(e));
            this.notifyService.notify(Copied!', 3000);
          }
        }
      )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. My solution was using **NgZone**

TS:

```js
import { Component, NgZone, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from 'src/app/shared/services/api.service';
import { Clipboard } from '@angular/cdk/clipboard';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-docs',
  templateUrl: './docs.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./docs.page.scss'],
})
export class DocsPage implements OnInit {

  token = '';

  constructor(
    private apiService: ApiService,
    private clipboard: Clipboard,
    private ngZone: NgZone
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  async generarToken() {
    const servicio = await this.apiService.loginServicio();
    this.token = servicio.token;

    this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const copyResponse = this.clipboard.copy('Bearer ' + this.token);
        console.log(copyResponse, this.clipboard); // now copyResponse is true
      });
    });
  }
}
```